# How can I identify impact on workflows, triggers, validation rules, etc,, when changing stage names or removing a stage?

Tags: reporting

Is there a free app exchange tool that will easily help identify what the impact would be on workflows, triggers, validation rules, etc,, when changing stage names or removing a stage? Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate about what kind of impact are you referring to? You can already use "debug logs" to look at how various workflows, validations and triggers are behaving for a given record.

Comment: Not sure how to access "debug logs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a tool like the Eclipse IDE to download all the metadata, you could search for the field name (in this case, `StageName`). I'm sure you could have a good picture about the impact of changing anything related to the field, since the search results will output Apex classes, Visualforce pages, components, Workflows, Validation rules and so on.

For anyone who's unfamiliar with Eclipse IDE, the Salesforce Developer [Introduction to Salesforce IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm) page is a good place to start.
It includes a 'getting started' section with a link to [Force.com IDE Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) that explains which Eclipse & Java software you'll need to download, in order to use the IDE.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer @RickNania, you can click the Checkmark icon next to my comment (left side).